# How RaspberryPi will scan the MAC address with Bluetoothctl?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

If the RSSI values for a permitted phone are above -60, I would like to log the phone's MAC address.

However, when I use Bluetoothctl on Raspberry Pi, I cannot see my phone MAC address unless I open the "Connected devices" page on the phone. Otherwise it scan.

I would like to know how RaspberryPi will scan the MAC address even if I don't open the "Connected devices" page. Any input or advice is greatly appreciated!

Aside from that, Bluetooth of car navigation system works without opening the "Connected devices" page...

Comment: You have put `python` as one of the tags so I'm assuming you have a script written in Python. If that is the case then you should be using the [BlueZ DB-us API](git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc ) to do the scan and not `bluetoothctl`. An example of doing this is at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114173/121848

Comment: thank you for your message. I test with this code(https://stackoverflow.com/a/65053417/17769908). I'm going to search about the [BlueZ DB-us API]

Comment: oops! I had a typo in my previous comment. It should have been `D-Bus`